# Quick way to reference an index of values inside one array column like bitzer(:,5)?

Tags: matlab

I want to reference an index of values inside the 5th column of an array like blitzer.

E.g. I want to access, say, all values of blitzer(:,5) where blitzer(:,4) < 10. This outputs an index of values. So maybe I could set blitzer5 = blitzer(:,5), and then call blitzer5(blitzer(:,4) < 10).

But is there a quick way to do this without having to create an entirely new vector? Ideally I'd like to call blitzer(:,5)[blitzer(:,4) < 10]. If so, how?

Comment: Can you try to be clearer about what you're asking? I've read several times and it makes no sense.

Comment: Why would `newvector(5)` give you the 8th element and not the 5th?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give vertical index from the matrix itself:

```
blitzer(blitzer(:,4) < 10,5)
```

This will give you elements from the 5-th column, where the corresponding elements in the 4-th row are less than 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference the 8th element in the 5th column of an array, you can write

```
theElement = blitzer(8,5)
```